# Basic use of Retrofit 2.0 with PUT method

Tags: android, put, retrofit2

How do I use `Retrofit 2.0` when my API returns these combinations for `PUT` requests:

- 201 - OK - `{ status: true }`
- 406 - Not Acceptable - `{ status: false, info: "string value" }`
- 500 - Not Acceptable - `{ status: false, info: "string value" }`

Which model should I use? With (`Boolean` and `String` or `String` and `String`)?

And how can I get `status` from this, because `response` -> `rawResponse` -> `code` e.g. equals 500, so I should get `status = false` and `info = "sth"`.

Now my app crashes with (`body = null`) when trying to receive this data.

Answer (score 1):

Which model should I use?

`boolean` for `status`
`String` for `info`

> And how can I get status from this, cause response -> rawResponse ->
>   code e.g. equals 500

In this case the body should be returned by `Response.errorBody()`

Comment: `if (response.body().isStatus()) { showToast(getApplicationContext(), "Registration ok."); } else {
                            showToast(getApplicationContext(), response.errorBody().what_should_be_here);
                        }` - I tried this - still nothing...

Comment: you shouldn't be using `getApplicationContext()` to handle ui. Is that snippet running on the UI Thread ?

Comment: It is running in `Activity` class

Comment: that doens't mean that it is running on the ui thread. Nevertheless, use the Activity's context instead of getApplicationContext to show the toast and see if it makes any difference

Comment: Didn't help. Don't know why always has `response body = null` in this `PUT` method... In `POST` method for login everything is just fine... Trying to register user via Postman and the same data = `{status: true}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below model

```
public class Response
{
  public Boolean status;
  public String info;
}
```